# Convert Array model object into JSON - Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have a function created to convert an Array to JSON, I wanted to use it for my Model since I have to convert it to an `AWSJSON` and it's not working.

Here's the error I get:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

in line `guard let data = try? JSONSerialization... below in the function`

Here's what the array contains

```
let chainsWithBalance = await tokenBalancesClassAViewModel.getChainsOnlyWithWalletBalance(wallet: walletAddress)
```

Now... when I print the variable above I get:

```
[appName.AllChainsItemsClassAModel(name: Optional("eth-mainnet"), chain_id: Optional("1"), db_schema_name: Optional("chain_eth_mainnet"), label: Optional("Ethereum Mainnet"), logo_url: Optional("https://www.covalenthq.com/static/images/icons/display-icons/ethereum-eth-logo.png"), is_testnet: Optional(false)), appName.AllChainsItemsClassAModel(name: Optional("matic-mainnet"), chain_id: Optional("137"), db_schema_name: Optional("chain_matic_mainnet"), label: Optional("Matic Mainnet"), logo_url: Optional("https://www.covalenthq.com/static/images/icons/display-icons/polygon-matic-logo.png"), is_testnet: Optional(false)), appName.AllChainsItemsClassAModel(name: Optional("bsc-mainnet"), chain_id: Optional("56"), db_schema_name: Optional("chain_bsc"), label: Optional("Binance Smart Chain"), logo_url: Optional("https://www.covalenthq.com/static/images/icons/display-icons/binance-coin-bnb-logo.png"), is_testnet: Optional(false))
]
```

Could it be that I have to loop through it and then re-assign to a new set of arrays unwrapping it?

Here's the function I'm using to convert it to JSON

```
func convertChainsIntoJSON(chains: [AllChainsItemsClassAModel]) -> String? {
    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: chains, options: []) else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

Here's the model I'm using:

```
struct AllChainsItemsClassAModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let name, chain_id, db_schema_name, label, logo_url: String?
    let is_testnet: Bool?
}
```

I'm puzzled by it, what's going on? The function works fine to convert an array of type `["a", "b"]`

Thanks

Comment: I’m a little confused. Your model looks nothing like the data in the first code block.

Comment: woops, I think I pasted the wrong model, give me a sec @jnpdx

Comment: @jnpdx corrected, good catch!

Comment: @jnpdx I added a couple of details on the actual data that is printed that might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom type conforms to the `Codable` protocol so make use of that instead

```
func convertChainsIntoJSON(chains: [AllChainsItemsClassAModel]) -> String? {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(chains) else { return nil }
    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

Comment: that worked beautifully and less code! Thanks :)